# Better way to test multiple websites through automation

Tags: web, automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I am trying to find a better automation tool to perform the websites testing automatically to identify the bugs using various mobile devices and browsers.

Tried with various no code automation tools and Browserstack and Lambdatest as well. but not able to acheive it perform automatically.

Comment: Browser stack and lambdatest are just tools for testing across platforms and not for no code tests, you can use selenium or Cypress to write your scripts and these platforms can help you run the tests on multiple browsers

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium seems to be the most popular option. However, I suggest Playwright. It has unique features to be able to open new pages, new tabs, new browsers and new windows with its Browser, BrowserContext and Page concept.